# How to set the scope for the HTML inside a directive (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

When I create a directive with `scope: {}`, a new, isolated scope is created for the directive and can be accessed inside the template.

But consider the following scenario:

```
<div my-directive>
  <p ng-bind="foo"></p>
</div>
```

I have some HTML inside the directive element (I am not using a template) and want this to get access to the directives' scope. Is this possible? Right now the scope inside the directive element refers to the parent scope outside the directive. Side note: I want to preserve the isolated scope.

Javascript for my-directive:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
      $scope.foo = 'bar';
    }
  }
});
```

Here's a plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/sSNy1p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually wouldn't want to have an isolated scope, either use `scope: true`, or omit the `scope` property altogether.

Here's a [<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/uQ3FMYdeeDwXgel5JoNY?p=preview) for this.

If you still want to use an isolated scope (and optionally have two way binding for properties), just include that inner HTML in the directive's template, e.g.:

```js
scope: {},
template: '<p ng-bind="foo"></p>',
```

Here's a [<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/PzC5t5dP3NuTvZcQVr6g?p=preview) for that.